# How can I get value of specific property of an object from the Nested array of objects of Mongodb with Java syntax?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, rest

I have two Mongodb documents

```
Document 1:
{
        "_id": "456f2c293b50d15ad7b84b37",
        "system": "Maruti",
        "article": {
            "number": "123456789",
            "description": "des",
            "toy": "super"
        }
}

Document 2:
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5678d3917b3d4f2a61a1a92d"), 
    "user" : "sample", 
    "Email" : "sample@gmail.com", 
    
    "Sample Systems" : [
        {
            "Car" : {
                "System" : "Maruti", 
                "indicator" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "Scooter" : {
                "System" : "TVS", 
                "indicator" : true
            }
        }
    ], 
 
}
```

And My URL is http://localhost:8080/?system=Maruti

I need to search the query based on input parameter if system = Maruti , from the second document I need to get the value of indicator of Sample Systems.Car.System =Maruti . In case in request parameter system =TVS , I need to take the value of indicator of Sample Systems.Scooter.System =TVS .There are so many systems in both documents dynamically get the value of based on system . I have tried with the below logic not getting the desired results .Not getting the logic to match the system from two documents .Can anyone help me with Java syntax how to match parameter from two documents.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/system", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object getSystem(@RequestParam(value = "system") String system){
    MongoDatabase database = this.mongoClient.getDatabase(test);
    MongoCollection<Document> users = database.getCollection(Systems);
     List<? extends Bson> pipelinesVal = Arrays.asList(
                new Document()
                        .append("$unwind", "$Sample Systems"),
                new Document()
                        .append("$match",  new Document().append("Sample Systems","$Sample Systems")),
                new Document()
                        .append("$project", new Document()
                                .append("_id", 1)
                                .append("Systems", 1)

                        ));
        List<Document> Val = new ArrayList<>();
        List values=users.aggregate(pipelinesVal).into(Val);
        Document system =new Document();
        List<Document> aggregate = new ArrayList<>();
        
}
```

Comment: can you please provide the expected sample response fro the sample request.

Comment: Thanks for to your reply , Sample response would be a document .Actually this is condition based search between two different collections. SourceSystem is input parameter ,the input parameter should be match in other collection which is Array of Objects .I am facing the issue to get the match value from  ArrayOfObjects .,Anyone can suggest .